Monitor is stuck at 30hz w/Linux. Is this Lenovo EDID the problem?
This EDID from a Lenovo P32p-20 4k monitor works ok in Windows at 4k@60hz but for Linux only 4k@30hz. Is the problem a flakey EDID or Linux decoding it? I note it says "EDID conformity: FAIL". The laptop's built-in panel (eDP-1) correctly shows "3840x2400 59.98*" but the external Lenovo monitor (DP-4) only goes to 30hz according to xrandr. OS is OpenSUSE w/KDE + Wayland however I think the desktop environment is unrelated because it's a kernel issue decoding the available modes, right?
edid-decode (hex):

00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 30 ae a2 62 00 00 00 00
1c 1e 01 04 b5 46 27 78 3a e5 a5 ae 4f 43 ab 26
0c 50 54 a1 08 00 d1 00 d1 c0 b3 00 81 c0 81 80
95 00 a9 c0 81 00 4d d0 00 a0 f0 70 3e 80 30 20
35 00 b9 88 21 00 00 1a 00 00 00 fd 00 17 4c 1e
a0 3c 01 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fc 00 4c
45 4e 20 50 33 32 70 2d 32 30 0a 20 00 00 00 ff
00 56 4e 41 34 59 35 33 52 0a 20 20 20 20 01 b7

02 03 1b f1 4e 61 60 5f 10 1f 05 14 04 13 12 11
03 02 01 23 09 7f 07 83 01 00 00 a3 66 00 a0 f0
70 1f 80 30 20 35 00 b9 88 21 00 00 1a 56 5e 00
a0 a0 a0 29 50 30 20 35 00 b9 88 21 00 00 1a 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0c

----------------

Block 0, Base EDID:
  EDID Structure Version & Revision: 1.4
  Vendor & Product Identification:
    Manufacturer: LEN
    Model: 25250
    Made in: week 28 of 2020
  Basic Display Parameters & Features:
    Digital display
    Bits per primary color channel: 10
    DisplayPort interface
    Maximum image size: 70 cm x 39 cm
    Gamma: 2.20
    DPMS levels: Off
    Supported color formats: RGB 4:4:4, YCrCb 4:4:4, YCrCb 4:2:2
    First detailed timing includes the native pixel format and preferred refresh rate
  Color Characteristics:
    Red  : 0.6826, 0.3105
    Green: 0.2626, 0.6689
    Blue : 0.1503, 0.0488
    White: 0.3134, 0.3291
  Established Timings I & II:
    IBM     :   720x400    70.081663 Hz   9:5     31.467 kHz     28.320000 MHz
    DMT 0x04:   640x480    59.940476 Hz   4:3     31.469 kHz     25.175000 MHz
    DMT 0x09:   800x600    60.316541 Hz   4:3     37.879 kHz     40.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x10:  1024x768    60.003840 Hz   4:3     48.363 kHz     65.000000 MHz
  Standard Timings:
    DMT 0x45:  1920x1200   59.884600 Hz  16:10    74.556 kHz    193.250000 MHz
    DMT 0x52:  1920x1080   60.000000 Hz  16:9     67.500 kHz    148.500000 MHz
    DMT 0x3a:  1680x1050   59.954250 Hz  16:10    65.290 kHz    146.250000 MHz
    DMT 0x55:  1280x720    60.000000 Hz  16:9     45.000 kHz     74.250000 MHz
    DMT 0x23:  1280x1024   60.019740 Hz   5:4     63.981 kHz    108.000000 MHz
    DMT 0x2f:  1440x900    59.887445 Hz  16:10    55.935 kHz    106.500000 MHz
    DMT 0x53:  1600x900    60.000000 Hz  16:9     60.000 kHz    108.000000 MHz (RB)
    DMT 0x1c:  1280x800    59.810326 Hz  16:10    49.702 kHz     83.500000 MHz
  Detailed Timing Descriptors:
    DTD 1:  3840x2160   59.996625 Hz  16:9    133.312 kHz    533.250000 MHz (697 mm x 392 mm)
                 Hfront   48 Hsync  32 Hback   80 Hpol P
                 Vfront    3 Vsync   5 Vback   54 Vpol N
    Display Range Limits:
      Monitor ranges (Bare Limits): 23-76 Hz V, 30-160 kHz H, max dotclock 600 MHz
    Display Product Name: 'LEN P32p-20'
    Display Product Serial Number: 'VNA4Y53R'
  Extension blocks: 1
Checksum: 0xb7

----------------

Block 1, CTA-861 Extension Block:
  Revision: 3
  Underscans IT Video Formats by default
  Basic audio support
  Supports YCbCr 4:4:4
  Supports YCbCr 4:2:2
  Native detailed modes: 1
  Video Data Block:
    VIC  97:  3840x2160   60.000000 Hz  16:9    135.000 kHz    594.000000 MHz
    VIC  96:  3840x2160   50.000000 Hz  16:9    112.500 kHz    594.000000 MHz
    VIC  95:  3840x2160   30.000000 Hz  16:9     67.500 kHz    297.000000 MHz
    VIC  16:  1920x1080   60.000000 Hz  16:9     67.500 kHz    148.500000 MHz
    VIC  31:  1920x1080   50.000000 Hz  16:9     56.250 kHz    148.500000 MHz
    VIC   5:  1920x1080i  60.000000 Hz  16:9     33.750 kHz     74.250000 MHz
    VIC  20:  1920x1080i  50.000000 Hz  16:9     28.125 kHz     74.250000 MHz
    VIC   4:  1280x720    60.000000 Hz  16:9     45.000 kHz     74.250000 MHz
    VIC  19:  1280x720    50.000000 Hz  16:9     37.500 kHz     74.250000 MHz
    VIC  18:   720x576    50.000000 Hz  16:9     31.250 kHz     27.000000 MHz
    VIC  17:   720x576    50.000000 Hz   4:3     31.250 kHz     27.000000 MHz
    VIC   3:   720x480    59.940060 Hz  16:9     31.469 kHz     27.000000 MHz
    VIC   2:   720x480    59.940060 Hz   4:3     31.469 kHz     27.000000 MHz
    VIC   1:   640x480    59.940476 Hz   4:3     31.469 kHz     25.175000 MHz
  Audio Data Block:
    Linear PCM:
      Max channels: 2
      Supported sample rates (kHz): 192 176.4 96 88.2 48 44.1 32
      Supported sample sizes (bits): 24 20 16
  Speaker Allocation Data Block:
    FL/FR - Front Left/Right
  Detailed Timing Descriptors:
    DTD 2:  3840x2160   29.980602 Hz  16:9     65.688 kHz    262.750000 MHz (697 mm x 392 mm)
                 Hfront   48 Hsync  32 Hback   80 Hpol P
                 Vfront    3 Vsync   5 Vback   23 Vpol N
    DTD 3:  2560x1440   59.950550 Hz  16:9     88.787 kHz    241.500000 MHz (697 mm x 392 mm)
                 Hfront   48 Hsync  32 Hback   80 Hpol P
                 Vfront    3 Vsync   5 Vback   33 Vpol N
Checksum: 0x0c

----------------

Preferred Video Timing if only Block 0 is parsed:
  DTD   1:  3840x2160   59.996625 Hz  16:9    133.312 kHz    533.250000 MHz (697 mm x 392 mm)
                 Hfront   48 Hsync  32 Hback   80 Hpol P
                 Vfront    3 Vsync   5 Vback   54 Vpol N

----------------

Preferred Video Timings if Block 0 and CTA-861 Blocks are parsed:
  DTD   1:  3840x2160   59.996625 Hz  16:9    133.312 kHz    533.250000 MHz (697 mm x 392 mm)
                 Hfront   48 Hsync  32 Hback   80 Hpol P
                 Vfront    3 Vsync   5 Vback   54 Vpol N
  VIC  97:  3840x2160   60.000000 Hz  16:9    135.000 kHz    594.000000 MHz
                 Hfront  176 Hsync  88 Hback  296 Hpol P
                 Vfront    8 Vsync  10 Vback   72 Vpol P

----------------

Native Video Resolution:
  3840x2160

----------------

edid-decode SHA: 84ddf9155376 2021-10-03 10:37:45

Warnings:

EDID:
  Base EDID: Some timings are out of range of the Monitor Ranges:
    Horizontal Freq: 28.125 - 135.000 kHz (Monitor: 30.000 - 160.000 kHz)

Failures:

Block 1, CTA-861 Extension Block:
  Missing VCDB, needed for Set Selectable RGB Quantization to avoid interop issues.

EDID conformity: FAIL


$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 10561 x 3780, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2400+0+1379 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 215mm
   3840x2400     59.98*+
   2048x1536     59.95  
   1920x1440     59.97  
   1600x1200     59.96  
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   2560x1600     59.99  
   1920x1200     59.96  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.97  
   960x600       59.96  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   3840x2160     60.00  
   3200x1800     59.99  
   2880x1620     60.00  
   2560x1440     59.96  
   2048x1152     59.98  
   1920x1080     59.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
DP-4 connected 6720x3780+3841+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   6720x3780     29.99*+
   2048x1536     29.95  
   1920x1440     29.95  
   1600x1200     29.95  
   1440x1080     29.86  
   1400x1050     29.98  
   1280x1024     29.90  
   1280x960      29.82  
   1152x864      29.92  
   1024x768      29.89  
   800x600       29.55  
   640x480       29.85  
   320x240       27.50  
   2560x1600     29.99  
   1920x1200     29.95  
   1680x1050     29.95  
   1440x900      29.91  
   1280x800      29.83  
   1152x720      29.96  
   960x600       29.86  
   928x580       29.64  
   800x500       29.53  
   768x480       29.64  
   720x480       29.25  
   640x400       29.58  
   320x200       26.53  
   5120x2880     29.99  
   4096x2304     29.99  
   3840x2160     29.98  
   3200x1800     29.96  
   2880x1620     29.96  
   2560x1440     29.94  
   2048x1152     29.94  
   1920x1080     29.95  
   1600x900      29.92  
   1368x768      29.94  
   1280x720      29.93  
   1024x576      29.84  
   864x486       29.50  
   720x400       29.51  
   640x350       29.03


